# Python: Appending to lists as keys within a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
def classify(kingdom, species):
""" (list of str, list of str) -> dict

classifies each of the species in the right class in the format of a dictionary
PRECONDITION: len(kingdom) = len(species)

>>>classify(['Animal', 'Animal', 'Plant', 'Protist'], ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Daffodil', 'Plankton'])
{'Animal' : ['Dog', 'Cat'], 'Plant' : ['Daffodil'], 'Protist' : ['Plankton']}
""""
```

I am trying to complete this function; however, i do not know how to assign a variable to a dictionary that uses lists as the values, nor do I know how to add new values to the list.

So far this is my attempt

```
def classify(kingdom, species):
d = {}
for j in range(len(kingdom)):
    d[kingdom[j]] = []
for k in range(len(species)):
    d[kingdom[k]].append(species[k])
return d
```

For some reason in returns the incorrect result.

```
>>>classify(['Animal', 'Animal', 'Plant', 'Protist'], ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Daffodil', 'Plankton'])
{'Protist': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Daffodil', 'Plankton'], 'Plant': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Daffodil', 'Plankton'], 'Animal': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Daffodil', 'Plankton']}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt, and what precisely is the problem with it? Have you read [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) on dictionaries and lists? Also, trying to use `class` as a parameter name is a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Sorry for not being too specific, I've included the details, and yes, I've read the tutorials. Class in this case is just a name of the parameter, but I've changed it for the sake of decorum.

Comment: `kingdom[1][j]` is going to be one of the letters in `'animal'`, which I doubt is what you're going for. Also, you're filling your dictionary with *references to the same list* - remove `b` and use the list literal `[]` directly to create new instances. Rather than just say *"incorrect result"*, **show what you got**.

Comment: Yes, because you're using the **same list object for every key**. Remove the name `b` from your code entirely, and assign a list literal `[]` directly into the dictionary.

Comment: Oh yes! That was the problem. I can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems.

First, everywhere you're using `kingdom[1]`, you should just be using `kingdom`. Seems like you used to have a function that took a single list containing two sublists, and you didn't update the code to correspond to the new signature.

Second, doing `d[kingdom[j]] = b` will cause all values in `d` to point to the exact same list. Appending to one of them will cause all the other ones to be appended to as well. Just assign a brand new list each time.

```
def classify(kingdom, species):
    d = {}
    for j in range(len(kingdom)):
        d[kingdom[j]] = []
    for k in range(len(species)):
        d[kingdom[k]].append(species[k])
    return d

print classify(['Animal', 'Animal', 'Plant', 'Protist'], ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Daffodil', 'Plankton'])
```

Result:

```
{'Plant': ['Daffodil'], 'Protist': ['Plankton'], 'Animal': ['Dog', 'Cat']}
```

---

Bonus: You may find it worthwhile to refactor your code. You can eliminate the first loop in your function if you make `d` a `collections.defaultdict`; you won't need to set up the lists, since they'll be created by default.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def classify(kingdom, species):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k in range(len(species)):
        d[kingdom[k]].append(species[k])
    return d
```

And you can make the second loop arguably more clear if you iterate through the lists' elements directly instead of iterating through their indices.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def classify(kingdom, species):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for name, kind in zip(species, kingdom):
        d[kind].append(name)
    return d
```